# Problems with Relationship Composite Primary Key on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this diagram
[image]

How can I create the relationship on Hibernate of the entities
EscalaDetalhes and DefinicaoEscala, because on DefiniciaoEscala entity there is a composite primary key formed by idDetalhe (foreign with (EscalaDetalhes)) and idTurma(foreign with (Turma)).

I've already done the class like below :

```
@Embeddable
public class DefinicaoEscalaPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="myColumn")
    private Integer idTurma;
    @Column(name="myColumn2")
    private Integer idEscalaDia;

    //GETTERS , SETTERS , HASH AND EQUALS
}

@Entity
public class DefinicaoEscala implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DefinicaoEscalaPK id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTurno")
    private TurnoBean turno;

    //GETTERS , SETTERS , HASH AND EQUALS
}


@Entity
@Table(name ="table")
public class EscalaDetalhes{
    @id
    private Integer idDetalhe;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="mybdColumn")
    private EscalaBean escala;
    @Column(name="myColumn") 
    private Calendar dia;
    //MY QUESTION IS HERE , HOW WOULD I DESCRIBE THE RELATION HERE?  
    private List<DefinicaoEscala> escalaDiaDetalhes;

    //GETTERS , SETTERS , HASH AND EQUALS

}
```

My question is here, How can I describe the relation?

`private List<DefinicaoEscala> escalaDiaDetalhes;`

Comment: Use ```@ForeignKey``` at the other table, I just forget how to set the id of the foreign object

Comment: Is there an example of how to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`referencedColumnName` is basically used to convey that which column of the other entity will be mapped could be used for mapping in the current entity, thus, you can use the property `referencedColumnName` while mentioning the relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="table")
public class EscalaDetalhes{
    @id
    private Integer idDetalhe;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="mybdColumn")
    private EscalaBean escala;
    @Column(name="myColumn") 
    private Calendar dia;
    //MY QUESTION IS HERE , HOW WOULD I DESCRIBE THE RELATION HERE? 
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="idDetalhe",referencedColumnName="idEscalaDia")
    private List<DefinicaoEscala> escalaDiaDetalhes;

    //GETTERS , SETTERS , HASH AND EQUALS

}
```

P.S: It is entirely on the basis of code you have shared.

Comment: I got the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: idEscalaDia in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(ESCALADETALHE) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Comment: Please correct the name of referenced column as per the refered column in DefinicaoEscala and make sure that column is mapped properly in DefinicaoEscala entity.  Your ER diagram and sample entities seem out of sync